# Auto-generated zone-identity files - Can/should I delete?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## Auto-generated Zone Files

---

### EDIT: (December 10th)

##### At the time of authoring this question...

...I didn't really have a clue as to why the `...:Zone.identifier` files were being created, or even when they were being created. It seemed very intermittent.

---

##### Now, I realize...

...I trigger their creation when I move files from my machines **`NTFS`** **file system**, into my machines **`EXT4`** **file system**. If it makes a difference, I *hotdrop* — or *drag n drop* — when moving the files, and I use the WSL Application **GWSL** to open the **`EXT4`** **file system**.

#### RECREATING

To recreate the issue (if you can call it an issue), really I believe windows is acting as it should be expected to, I just don't want windows creating them, but at this point I don't know if that's a bad idea. Either way, to recreate the issue, you should see them created by drag & dropping a file from your Windows 10/11 file system into your Linux WSL EXT4 File system.

###### END OF EDIT

---

## ORIGINAL POST

---

First, I'd like to point out that I researched this topic, and was surprised, to find that `:Zone.identifier` files are a feature that has been implemented by Microsoft, in their Windows Operating Systems, for quite some time now. They started using the feature pre-`WSL` when a non-integrated VM was required for using Linux in a Windows environment. What is most surprising is it doesn't seem to bother many people, but having files, files that I never knowingly gave permission to create, popup all over my file-system, is driving my bonkers. As far as I can tell, or from what I have gathered around the internet, the files allow windows hidden files to be created in the Linux Operating System that runs in WSL (or WSL2 in my case). In truth, I don't fully understand the purpose for the implementation of the `:Zone` files feature (or concept if you will). The most I have come to gather, is that they have something to do with creating hidden files, but I can't find a clear answer on this topic, and I wish I could find out more about these files. Most importantly, though, is my question...

> *"How does a person go about disabling the feature responsible for creating `:Zone.identifier` files? And what are the consequences of doing so?"*

[image: image of a zone.identifier file]

My search returned [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65101/what-are-these-files-like-zone-identifierdata-and-how-to-prevent-them) on the SuperUser sister site Ask Ubuntu.  Unfortunately, even though it answers my question, it answers it for the *much* older Windows Version/Edition: Windows XP. I figure that it's still a security policy, as shown in that post, but navigating to it seems to have changed.

###### FYI, I am asking because I don't want to go and start playing with configurations that I don't know what they do. I got work stuff on my computer that would be catastrophic to lose. I want to know what I am doing before I just go flipping switches.

Comment: Good to "see" you again.  Can you provide more detail on exactly what process you are doing when these are created?  Is it a browser (and if so, which) download to `\\wsl$\<distro>`?  Or something else?  I haven't been able to recreate it yet.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I wrote a comment to you, but I decided to edit the comment into the post, as its content seemed more appropriately located in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need those if you copy same folder back to ntfs side. So after copying there you can remove those files by running following in the command line.

```
myfolder_copied_from_wsl>DEL /S /Q *.Identifier
```