# Deleting files and emptying trash in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have just installed WSL on my pc with windows 11.

I want to delete files from Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL.

I did:

```
gio trash someFile
```

This went to .local/share/Trash/files.

If I do gio trash --empty it will not empty the trashed files. Anyway to do this? Do I have to create a custom alias to `rm -rf .local/share/Trash/files/*`?

Can I use gio trash to send the files to Windows bin?

Additionally, when I copied files from windows to Ubuntu I got a zone.Identifier file... are they normal? Can I remove them?

Best regards

Comment: See if [this method](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/h7f6fv/guide_how_to_integrate_wsl_with_the_windows/) works.

Comment: Regarding Zone.Identifier files, see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1692240/1210833).  It doesn't have any answers, but at least there's some more research from the OP about the files.  I was never able to reproduce this behavior myself.  Are you using GWSL by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

*Just a heads-up that I deleted my previous answer since (a) it was missing some information that was critical to make this work, (b) I found a somewhat easier method of getting trash to work anyway, and (c) my original answer didn't quite address your question(s).  This is a complete rewrite-from-scratch.*

You seem to have three main (somewhat related) questions in your post, with several implied questions that result:

- *Is there a way to get `gio trash --empty` to empty the trash?*

  I'll start with why it isn't working out-of-the-box with WSL.

  `gio` relies on the Gnome Virtual File System (GVfs) for some of its functionality, which in turn relies on a user-session D-Bus, which in another turn is usually started by Systemd under Ubuntu.  Ultimately, the `gio trash --empty` isn't doing anything because:

  1. The `gvfs` package isn't installed by default in Ubuntu under WSL.
  2. Systemd doesn't (easily) run under WSL, so D-Bus is never launched.

  *(Note: see footnote at end on why `gio trash filename` works anyway)*

  If you'd like to enable the feature, you can:

  - Install GVfs with `sudo apt install gvfs`.  Note that my previous answer did not have this information, since I already had it installed as a dependency of another package.  Without GVfs, the previous answer probably wouldn't work for you.
  - With GVfs now installed, you can run WSL using the following command-line:

    ```
    wsl dbus-launch --exit-with-session bash # or tmux, or whatever shell you prefer
    ```

  Trash should work properly, including `gio list Trash://`, at least for local files.

  You can change your Windows Terminal profile to use that commandline, if you'd like.  That way it will always start with your WSL instance.

  If you don't want to do that, then sure, an `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*` will essentially have the same effect, which not using `gio`, `gvfs`, or `dbus`.  And you can alias this or write a function to make it easier if you'd like.

---

- *Can `gio` send WSL/Linux/Ubuntu files to the Windows Recycle Bin?  If not, is there another way to send WSL files to the Windows Recycle Bin?*

  For the first part, I'm just going to go with, "No. `gio` cannot send files to the Windows Recycle Bin."  Technically I believe it *could*, if someone wrote a GVfs module to manage it.  Since one doesn't exist, however, and neither you nor I (nor likely anyone else) probably has any intention of ever writing one, let's just call it "no."

  As for sending files to the Windows Recycle Bin from WSL with other methods, there are two possibilities that I can think of:

  - As harrymc mentioned in the comments, you could run a third-party tool to move files to the Windows Recycle bin. The linked Reddit post mentions `recycle.exe`.
  - It should also be relatively painless to do this through a PowerShell script running in WSL as mentioned in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502002/11810933). It should be entirely possible to get this working in WSL via a shell function or alias.

    I may come back to this as a side-project and attempt it myself, but for now I'm going to have to leave it as an exercise for someone else.

  For either of these techniques, note that for any file that isn't in the current directory, a Windows-based tool will need a path translation from Linux to Windows. This can be done with the wslpath tool that is built in to WSL. For instance:

  ```
  recycle.exe "$(wslpath -w <directory>/<filename)"
  ```

---

- *What are Zone.Indentifier files and is it safe to remove them?*

  Since this is covered by a [question already here on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1692240/1210833), I'm going to refer you there instead. Unfortunately, it doesn't have any answers, but at least there's some more research from the OP about the files. I was never able to reproduce this behavior myself. Are you using GWSL by any chance like the OP of that question?

---

*Footnote*

I did find it a bit odd that `gio trash filename` would work (move the file to the trash), but `gio trash --empty` would not, so I dug into the [gio source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/tree/main/gio) a bit.

As near as I can tell, if the file is a local file, it just does a simple rename of the file to place it in the proper Trash directory. This doesn't require the use of gvfs proper.

Emptying the trash, however, does apparently work through gvfs/dbus. I'm assuming this is since the trash may have more than just *local* files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed reply. In any case, I can use `gio trash someFile` and create the alias to remove it from the trash in Ubuntu, right?

Comment: @ThomasJerry Sure!  You're correct that I had that in the previous answer (a confirmation of your proposal) but left it out here.  Thanks!